# What are these additional properties in the state object of redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning the meats and potatoes of react redux. I was logging the state object from the reducer. But I see this nodes 1:a, 2:b, etc. What are these for ?[image]

This is my reducer code and I just calling the recipepuppy API

```
import { MAKE_REQUEST, LOAD_SEARCH_RESULTS, SEARCH_FAILED } from "../../constants/actionTypes";
const initialState = {
    isRequesting: true,
    searchTerm: '',
    searchFailed: false,
    searchSuccessful: false,
    searchResults: []
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("Original state" + state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case MAKE_REQUEST:

            let requestState = Object.assign({}, state, action.searchTerm, { isRequesting: true });
            console.log(requestState);
            return requestState;

        case LOAD_SEARCH_RESULTS:
            var results = action.searchResults.map(({ thumbnail, title, href }) => { return { thumbnail, title, href } });
            let searchResultState = Object.assign({}, state, { isRequesting: false, searchSuccessful: true, searchFailed: false, searchResults: results });
            console.log(searchResultState);
            return searchResultState;

        case SEARCH_FAILED:
            let searchFailState = Object.assign({}, state, { isRequesting: false, searchSuccessful: false, searchFailed: true, searchResults: [] });
            console.log(searchFailState);
            return searchFailState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: This appears to be specific to your code. My guess is that you are using the spread operator on a string and inserting it into your store somewhere. `console.log({..."cake"})` will create a similar effect.

Comment: You should post your reducer code.

Comment: @Max I just posted the reducer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case statement, I assume that `action.searchTerm` is a string. Try executing `Object.assign({}, 'cake')` in the console. It will return `{0: "c", 1: "a", 2: "k", 3: "e"}` because you are assigning the string to a new object as an object.

If you want your state to have a property called `searchTerm` with the value of `action.searchTerm` do this instead:

```
Object.assign({}, state, { isRequesting: true, searchTerm: action.searchTerm });
```